# Locate answer SDP packet in Wireshark

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, sdp

I'm tracing packets between 2 agents. One is from Chrome on Mac, the other is from Chrome Beta on Android. They're communicating by a reference site like apprtc.appspot.com and I managed to save [some logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Ow9f5ifXyFRXp0ajUwTVhnOWs/view?usp=sharing) out of it. (please download it or it only displayed as source code) Doing so I also capture packets in Wireshark while 2 agents communicating with WebRTC.

Using filter: stun||udp lots of Binding requests & responses can be founded.

Basically from the [rfc doc](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-mmusic-trickle-ice-00.txt) it said:

```
An agent can respond to an initial offer at any point while gathering candidates...
thus allowing the remote party to also start forming checklists and performing 
connectivity checks.
```

But I just can't see any sign of SDP like offer or answer sending to each other, which can be found in js log above. For cross reference I hope to find the right order of the entire communication.

Here's the [Wireshark file kinda of big](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Ow9f5ifXyFYUlzcnZuemliTkk&authuser=0)

Comment: The SDP is sent over whatever signalling system you have in place. So, it would be a packet sent to the signalling server(could be secured or not).

Comment: There're some packets between local agent & signalling server on the GAE. Protocols include QUIC, TLSv1.2 and TCP. Most packets are QUIC. And it appear some "application data" encrypted with TLSv1.2 from local to GAE server. Could it be SDP data?

Comment: That could be SDP data, and also Ice Candidates and any other information that is exchanged through the signalling server.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome uses TLS to encrypt the signaling packets. And if its a communication directly between the peer, the only way to see signaling is looking at the Console logs of chrome. It should have the offer answer exchange of the SDP. I am assuming its using SIP as the signaling protocol and you should be seeing it in the console.

If there is a intermediary between the peer, like a FreeSwitch any other SIP Server, it could be possible to debug it better as they have the keys to decode and find use the raw text messages.

Comment: From console log of Chrome there are offer & answer SDP printed. And I thought before connectivity check & done, exchanging candidate and SDP is communicated through signalling server. Is that right?

Comment: Well in my case it's using Google App Engine Channel API as signalling protocol because it's just a clone of apprtc.appspot.com.

Comment: Chrome will only send the packets with TLS if the signalling server connection is secured(websockets over SSL or something similar).